# Redirect string to file path that is read from input as string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have this command

```
echo "some text" >> ~/asd/file_name
```

and it works great,but when I read the path from input like this

```
var_name="~/asd/file_name"
```

then this does not work

```
echo "some text" >> $var_name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use tilde in double quotes. Tilde expansion happens in simple assignment, though:

```
var_name=~/asd/filename
```

You can use `$HOME` instead of `~` in double quotes.

Comment: how do I replace ~ with $HOME ?

Comment: @Lukap: `var_name="$HOME/asd/file_name"`.

Answer (score 3):

`~` is a special character that gets expanded by the shell when it's not quoted, as in your first command. 
When you use quotes, as in your second, the `~` does not get expanded.

Comment: how do I expand the ~ ?

Comment: You don't quote it during the assignment. Or use `"$HOME/..."`